# Если в базе поле заполнено как text, то вывести текст, если цифры, то вывести цифры

Tags: java, android, sql, строки, int

Возникла проблема, сейчас пользователи могут заполнить поле как цифрами так и не заполнять его вообще (заполнится автоматически текстом)

На странице вывода, стоит проверка

```
 if (objects.get(position).getPrice().matches("[0-9]+")) {
            holder.tvPrice.setText(objects.get(position).getCurrency_symbol() + objects.get(position).getPrice());
         holder.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           holder.tvPrice2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        } else if (objects.get(position).getPrice().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            holder.tvPrice2.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.price3));
           holder.tvPrice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          holder.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

Но при скролле вниз текст иногда пропдает и вместо него цена из другого обьекта
если срколлю вверх и перезагружаю view, то цена пропадает и появляется текст.

Никак не могу побороть эту проблему

Подскажите, что не так?

Спасибо

Comment: Я так понимаю используется RecyclerView? Плохой способ использовать вложенное условие для holder, из-за этого кэш не правильно работает. Сделай обычное условие, если только цифры - то это цена, иначе текст. И ошибка при скролле должна уйти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конвертнуть в инт и проверить на нулл, если нул - текст, иначе - цифра